# How to use material color of Vuetify in SCSS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use material color variable of Vuetify.

I read below page:
https://vuetifyjs.com/ja/styles/colors

And wrote like this:

```
$color-pack: false;
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/main.sass';

span {
  color: $teal;
}
```

But I got this Error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: ("base": #009688, "lighten-5": #e0f2f1, "lighten-4": #b2dfdb, "lighten-3": #80cbc4, "lighten-2": #4db6ac, "lighten-1": #26a69a, "darken-1": #00897b, "darken-2": #00796b, "darken-3": #00695c, "darken-4": #004d40, "accent-1": #a7ffeb, "accent-2": #64ffda, "accent-3": #1de9b6, "accent-4": #00bfa5) isn't a valid CSS value.
```

How can I solve this probrem?

Comment: I would check sass version and probably update. there are often problems with sass/sass loader not being compatible. check vuetify doc to see which version you need.

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables#sass-variables
states you should have sass-loader 8. maybe try the config mentioned there